# Excel Forumla for SUMPRODUCT to exclude rows/cols

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I am rather new to using Excel. How can I take a formula like this

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B3:B39, A3:A39)
```

and have it exclude specific rows that I am using as headers/dividers. But seem to break the formula if I insert a new row here or there on occasion.

Example rows 1, 2 and 14 for me are just a line of text bold, with a background color but the text is in the `A` column

I know when I use `=SUM()` If I have a similar setup, and insert a row/delete a row the numbers will update automatically. Guessing its not the case with `=SUMPRODUCT()`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. You're saying that the formula stops working if you have text values in the range? It is not happening like that for me.

Comment: I'm also not sure what the issue you are having is.  `sumproduct` just ignores rows that have invalid data (text) in them, it still should sum up the rest of the rows

Comment: Please provide an example of data from a portion of your spreadsheet that breaks when you insert rows and how you are adding rows to break it... A simple replication of this document structure does not produce any errors (Excel 2010).